# Probability of ever visiting a point in $2$D random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

[image: 2-D random walk]

At point $A$, the probability of moving up is $q$ and the probability of moving down is $p$. At point $B$, the probability of moving left is $x$, the probability of moving right is $y$ and the probability of moving up is $z$. Every point on the vertical line except the bottom one is similar to point $A$ and every point on the bottom horizontal line is similar to point $B$. What's the probability of an article ever reaches point $C$ when the starting point is $A$?

I know in $1$-D random walk, like on the vertical line, the probability of an article ever reaches point $B$ when the starting point is $A$ is $\dfrac{p}{q}$ but how to calculate it in $2$-D? Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be $$\frac{px}{px+q(1-zp)+py}$$

Comment: Let $D$ denote the symmetrical point of $C$ with respect to $B$, then, using notations that should be obvious, $P_A(\text{hits}\ C)=P_A(\text{hits}\ B)P_B(\text{hits}\ C)$. You know that $P_A(\text{hits}\ B)=\min(p/q,1)$. Furthermore, $P_B(\text{hits}\ C)=x+yP_D(\text{hits}\ C)+zP_A(\text{hits}\ C)$ and $P_D(\text{hits}\ C)=P_B(\text{hits}\ C)^2$. This yields $P_B(\text{hits}\ C)$, then the desired $P_A(\text{hits}\ C)$.

Comment: @Nikunj This formula seems to fail in some simple cases.

Comment: @Did please give an example?

Comment: @Nikunj p=q, x=y=z. Did you check any case yourself?

Comment: @Did yes, I checked to see what would happen if I plug in $p=0,q=0$ e.t.c and see what would happen

Comment: @Did but can't it be said that the total probability would be $$\frac {\text{Favorable paths}}{\text{Total possible paths}}?$$

Comment: @Nikunj $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$? Hmmm...

Comment: @Did you can't say that favourable paths will be infinite! It **has** to go from A to B to C, in between it can oscillate infinite times between B and A,   but the probabilities form a geometric progression and so I had considered them, but you are right, my formula is incorrect

Comment: @Nikunj The only way I know to make sense of your formula is that the numerator and the denominator enumerate paths and, yes, one can very much say that the number of paths involved are infinite. If you mean otherwise, please explain. (And anyway, the fact is that the formula you suggest does not provide the correct answer in some specific cases where one can check it.)